# How can we cast context to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {
    private UpdateMapAfterUserInterection updateMapAfterUserInterection;

    public TouchableWrapper(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        try {
            updateMapAfterUserInterection = (spare) context;
            // spare is fragment
            // this line throws 'cannot cast context to fragment' 
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement UpdateMapAfterUserInterection");
        }
    }
    Point touchPoint = new Point();
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(ev.getPointerCount()<2) {
                    final Point newTouchPoint = new Point();  // the new position of user's finger on screen after movement is detected
                    newTouchPoint.x = (int) ev.getX();
                    newTouchPoint.y = (int) ev.getY();
                    updateMapAfterUserInterection.onUpdateMapAfterUserInterection(touchPoint,newTouchPoint);
                    touchPoint = newTouchPoint;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.i("","up");
                break;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    // Map Activity must implement this interface
    public interface UpdateMapAfterUserInterection {
        public void onUpdateMapAfterUserInterection(Point touchpoint, Point newTouchpoint);
    }
```

I've made an interface with a function onUpdateMapAfterUserInterection
now I want the object updateMapAfterUserInterection to have the context of fragment 'spare' to update the map.
but it throws 'cannot cast context to fragment'
What can be the workaround?

Comment: That's not going to work. Instead, create a public setter method for your `UpdateMapAfterUserInterection` interface, just like setting an `OnClickListener` on a `View`.

Comment: You are trying to cast "EYE" class into "Human" class.

Comment: Fragment is not a Context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you.

Step 1: In **TouchableWrapper** class add this block

```
public void setUpdateMapAfterUserInterection(UpdateMapAfterUserInterection listener) {
       updateMapAfterUserInterection = listener;
}
```

Step 2: In your ***spare*** fragment, add below block to ***onCreateView*** method

```
TouchableWrapper view = findViewById(R.id.your_touchable_wrapper);
view.setUpdateMapAfterUserInterection(this);
```

**Update:** If you create TouchableWrapper view by code, then

```
TouchableWrapper view = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
view.setUpdateMapAfterUserInterection(this);
// TODO: Make sure you add this custom view to root view of your activity/fragment.
...
```

Comment: I have created a class https://pastebin.com/KdGA0MWy which extends SuportMapFragment and used in xml as https://pastebin.com/Yw4TwkW6